# meteorjs checking for logged in user

Tags: meteor

I have just picked up meteor again and a few things have changed since I last worked on my app. I have 1 issue at the moment whereby I want to present a login form if the user is not logged in. Previously I was using:

```
Deps.autorun(function(){
if(Meteor.userId()==null){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#loginModal').modal('show');
    });
}});
```

Which worked fine. Now, however I get an error:

**Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls**

So, how do I now achieve the above.
Thanks in advance
Adam

Comment: if(!Meteor.userId()){ // user not login.. do sonmething}

Comment: Alternatively, `if (!Meteor.loggingIn() && !Meteor.userId())`

Comment: Hi, the problem is that Meteor.userId() is not allowed to be invoked here. I know alternative ways to check an objects existence :) but not sure how to check within Deps.autorun.

Comment: Is any other function or codes wrap up these codes? It works fine in my computer

Comment: @tweakmag Woah, I completely misread your question. Sorry about that, I mustve been braindead. What version of meteor are you on? The docs for 0.9.4 claims Meteor userId is available anywhere but publish functions.

Comment: I am using 0.9.4 - but all good I have gone down a different path to achieve what I want which is similar to what Steffo posted below. What I was trying to do was use some javascript to "unhide" some elements if user wasnt logged in. But it is better to dynamically render instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I do:  on the server side with `iron:router` with `alanning:roles` you can do

```
this.route('EndUserPage', {
      path: '/EndUserPage',
      onBeforeAction: function (pause) {
          if (!(Meteor.user())) {
              console.log("Not logged in");
              this.setLayout('LoginForm');
              this.render('LoginForm');
          } else if (!(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin'))) {
              this.redirect("/AdminPage")
          } else {
              this.render();
          }
      }   });
```

If you don't have the roles package, you cannot check if it's an admin user, but the redirect to the login page would work as desired.